# Is it possible to start an infinite loop within init.d?

Tags: shell, init.d

I would like to create an init.d script to control the fan of my Odroid XU3 under Lollipop 5.1.1, CyanogenMod 12.1.

I already make one on linux which is working well and would like to port it to android.

The script is an infinite loop which is active every 5 secs. Is the Android init.d module able to use an infinite loop will it brick the device ?

https://github.com/AlexisTM/Odroid-XU3-Fan-Control-services

Comment: Couldn't you run that loop in a script file (using e.g. `while TRUE`), and start it as a "daemon" in the background (i.e. with an `&` appended on its call)?

Comment: Sure I can ! It was just for information ! Thanks !